# Unable to send Gmail Message with Gmail API

Tags: ruby, gmail, gmail-api, google-api-ruby-client

Using the [Gmail Service](https://googleapis.dev/ruby/google-api-client/latest/Google/Apis/GmailV1/GmailService.html) to send an email, but I'm having problem with the email format which needs to be passed to `Google::Apis::GmailV1::Message`, I'm passing raw parameter to it in the following format

```
email_raw = "From: <#{@google_account}>
To: <#{send_to}>
Subject: This is the email subject

The email body text goes here"

# raw is: The entire email message in an RFC 2822 formatted and base64url encoded string.

message_to_send = Google::Apis::GmailV1::Message.new(raw: Base64.encode64(email_raw))
response = @service.send_user_message("me", message_to_send)
```

This fails even when I pass `email_raw` without base64 encoding. I'm providing valid emails but it fails with an error

> Google::Apis::ClientError (invalidArgument: Recipient address required)

I've checked [Sending an email with ruby gmail api v0.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40246931/sending-an-email-with-ruby-gmail-api-v0-9) and I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48497583/rails-send-email-using-gmail-api-with-attachment-return-only-encoded-file-not) but it uses `Mail` class which I could not locate in the Gmail API Ruby client library. Currently, `email_raw` contains `\n` characters but I've tested it without it and it doesn't work. 
Moreover, I also want to send attachments in a message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can easily offload the effort of forming a standardized and formatted email to this [gem](https://github.com/mikel/mail). Just include the gem in your project and do this

```
mail = Mail.new
mail.subject = "This is the subject"
mail.to = "someperson@gmail.com"
# to add your html and plain text content, do this
mail.part content_type: 'multipart/alternative' do |part|
  part.html_part = Mail::Part.new(body: email_body, content_type: 'text/html')
  part.text_part = Mail::Part.new(body: email_body)
end
# to add an attachment, do this
mail.add_file(params["file"].tempfile.path)

# when you do mail.to_s it forms a raw email text string which you can supply to the raw argument of Message object
message_to_send = Google::Apis::GmailV1::Message.new(raw: mail.to_s)
# @service is an instance of Google::Apis::GmailV1::GmailService
response = @service.send_user_message("me", message_to_send)
```

Comment: You could also try using Aurinko's unified API when working with Gmail API https://apirefs.aurinko.io/#operation/send

Answer (score 1):

### Mind that Gmail requires base64url encoding, not base64 encoding

See [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages):

> raw   string (bytes format)

> The entire email message in an RFC 2822 formatted and base64url encoded string. Returned in messages.get and drafts.get responses when the format=RAW parameter is supplied.

> A base64-encoded string.

I recommend you to test first with the [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/send) - you can encode the message with online base64url encoders.

Then, when using Ruby, you can use the method:

`Base64.urlsafe_encode64(message)`.

### UPDATE

The problem seems to be your raw message body.

The message body should have the followind structure:

```
To: masroorh7@gmail.com Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="000000000000f1f8eb05b18e8970"  --000000000000f1f8eb05b18e8970 Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"  This is a test email  --000000000000f1f8eb05b18e8970 Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"  <div dir="ltr">This is a test email</div>  --000000000000f1f8eb05b18e8970--
```

base64url encoded, this will look like:

```
encodedMessage = "VG86IG1hc3Jvb3JoN0BnbWFpbC5jb20NCkNvbnRlbnQtVHlwZTogbXVsdGlwYXJ0L2FsdGVybmF0aXZlOyBib3VuZGFyeT0iMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwZjFmOGViMDViMThlODk3MCINCg0KLS0wMDAwMDAwMDAwMDBmMWY4ZWIwNWIxOGU4OTcwDQpDb250ZW50LVR5cGU6IHRleHQvcGxhaW47IGNoYXJzZXQ9IlVURi04Ig0KDQpUaGlzIGlzIGEgdGVzdCBlbWFpbA0KDQotLTAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMGYxZjhlYjA1YjE4ZTg5NzANCkNvbnRlbnQtVHlwZTogdGV4dC9odG1sOyBjaGFyc2V0PSJVVEYtOCINCg0KPGRpdiBkaXI9Imx0ciI-VGhpcyBpcyBhIHRlc3QgZW1haWw8L2Rpdj4NCg0KLS0wMDAwMDAwMDAwMDBmMWY4ZWIwNWIxOGU4OTcwLS0"
```

Thus, your message body should be:

```
Google::Apis::GmailV1::Message.new(raw:encodedMessage)
```

Comment: tried it, and still I get the same error: 400 "Recipient address required". The issue lies in the email_raw data

Comment: I see, in this case I recommend you to open any email in the Gmail UI, click on the "three dots", `Show original`, and use the `From`, `To` and everything below `Content-Type:` as a template for your message - to make sure that the formating is correct.

Comment: please have a look my attempt with the email's original message format here https://0bin.net/paste/SOT94vCA#o-HVmtBvLG8w7MB9dY1cFL/NMtaFtugUmk2gkw+8Zof it keeps giving the same error

Comment: Is `masrooratwork@gmail.com` your primary email? Try: `From: <masrooratwork@gmail.com>`,  and do NOT remove the boundaries and the `--`.  Removing `Date` and `Message-ID` is correct.

Comment: yes masrooratwork@gmail.com is the email I've authorized with, and I'm trying to send emails from this account. Sadly, the error is persisting after all these changes(included boundaries and --)

Comment: Do yo experience the same error when trying to send an email with the Try This API?

Comment: not the same error though but the raw input still has problems, see this https://0bin.net/paste/dUbzs-AD#9f7ZVlt48zHmWBKg2-tkn8Lm4A/0e4RiRFAfRZ/2PbK

Comment: It has worked when I tried sending the message without encoding.

Comment: Please try to send from the Try this API a message with userId `me` and the Base64Url encoded content `To: masroorh7@gmail.com
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="000000000000f1f8eb05b18e8970"

--000000000000f1f8eb05b18e8970
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"

This is a test email

--000000000000f1f8eb05b18e8970
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"

<div dir="ltr">This is a test email</div>

--000000000000f1f8eb05b18e8970--`

Comment: I tried your encodedMessage as input to raw and it worked in the Try this API. But the problem is I do not have any boundary or -- strings so what do I do about them? I only have To, From, Subject and Email body. There should be a way to make it work without providing any boundary and -- strings.

Comment: The boundaries are an obligatory part of the message body. They delimit the header. the plain text and the html parts of the message body.

Comment: okay fair enough, but how do I generate them? I have no way of making up these things on my own, nor there is any documentation about it. The API just demands RFC 2822 formatted raw text. Btw, thanks for all your effort, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Have a read a bout MIME messages: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME

Comment: Yes with every step you got me closer to the answer. I found something to take care of the RFC format. I'll update my answer.